# Sprint-boot executable same sources multiple jars

Tags: spring-boot, executable, spring-boot-maven-plugin

I did the following steps in order to run 2 instances of my spring-boot application on the **same host**:

- build jar with spring-boot maven plugin repackage goal
- copy application.jar to application-0.jar on my remote server
- created a application-0.conf file with APP_NAME=application-0
- start application-0.jar as a service
- copy application.jar to application-1.jar on my remote server
- created a application-1.conf file with APP_NAME=application-1
- start application-1.jar as a service

Then I got the following error upon application-1 start: **service application already provided!**

So I realized that:

- linux service name is hard coded in the jar so no matter how many times you copy the jar en rename it, the service will remain the same (in our case application service)
- APP_NAME has no effect on the service name. The APP_NAME in the .conf files were respectively set to application-0 and application-1. I still got the issue.

I read the spring-boot plugin documentation and tried an unsuccessful compination of **attach**, **classifier** and **embeddedLaunchScriptProperties.initInfoProvides** options on different spring-boot maven plugin executions of the same build.

I also tried to encapsulate different executions on separate maven profiles. I still got one original jar file and one single spring-boot jar.

So if anyone knows how to achieve my goal (same source, multiple well configured linux services since I run on the same host) I would really appreciate the help.

Below an example of unsuccessful configuration:

```html
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>classic</id>
      <goals>
        <goal>repackage</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <executable>true</executable>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
    <execution>
      <id>instance-0</id>
      <goals>
        <goal>repackage</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <finalName>${project.artifactId}-0</finalName>
        <executable>true</executable>
        <classifier>exec</classifier>
        <attach>false</attach>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
    <execution>
      <id>instance-1</id>
      <goals>
        <goal>repackage</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <finalName>${project.artifactId}-1</finalName>
        <executable>true</executable>
        <classifier>exec</classifier>
        <attach>false</attach>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

Thank you

Comment: the doc says "Spring Boot application can be easily started as Unix/Linux services using either init.d or systemd". How did you do it ?

Comment: Hi Alex, I used init.d (symlinking application.jar to /etc/init.d/application.jar)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the issue by using **systemd**:

- build **single** **executable** jar (no multiple spring boot plugin execution, no maven profile, just regular repackage executable goal)
- make it available at an absolute path (/var/xxx/application.jar)
- create any /etc/systemd/system/application-{i}.service you wish with the following config

  [Unit]
  Description=application-{i}
  After=syslog.target

  [Service]
  ExecStart=/var/xxx/application.jar --server.port=4500{i} --    logging.file=/var/log/xxx/application-{i}.log

  [Install]
  WantedBy=multi-user.target

Note the place holders {i} to avoid conflicts on service name, linstening ports and log file.

Systemd solved my issue.

Note: you are only concerned with my issue if you run same instances of your service on the same host. All this config is not needed if you run one service instance per host (common microservice approach).

Hope this helps anyone with the same issue.